# Regular expression: extract string between two characters/strings

Tags: r, regex, formula

I have a model formula (as string) and want to extract the value for a specific argument, `id` in my case. Now I have found a way that returns the string *without* the needed string value. I want exactly the opposite, I *only* want the string value that is missing in my result:

```
xx <- "gee(formula = breaks ~ tension, id = wool, data = warpbreaks)"
sub("(?=(id=|id =))([a-zA-Z].*)(?=,)", "\\1", xx, perl =T)
#> [1] "gee(formula = breaks ~ tension, id =, data = warpbreaks)"
```

`wool` is missing in the return value, but I only want to have `wool` as resulting string... Can anyone help me finding the correct regex pattern?

Comment: This will do it: `sub(".*id ?= ?(.*?),.*", "\\1", xx)`. You need to match the whole string.

Comment: Works like a charme, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
xx <- "gee(formula = breaks ~ tension, id = wool, data = warpbreaks)"
sub(".*\\bid\\s*=\\s*(\\w+).*", "\\1", xx)
## or, if the value extracted may contain any chars but commas
sub(".*\\bid\\s*=\\s*([^,]+).*", "\\1", xx)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/FnNIGX) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KBLu48/1).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\\bid` - a whole word `id` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `\\s*=\\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\\w+)` - Capturing group 1 (`\\1` in the replacement pattern refers to this value): one or more letters, digits or underscores (or `[^,]+` matches 1+ chars other than a comma)
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Other alternative solutions:

```
> xx <- "gee(formula = breaks ~ tension, id = wool, data = warpbreaks)"
> regmatches(xx, regexpr("\\bid\\s*=\\s*\\K[^,]+", xx, perl=TRUE))
[1] "wool"
```

The pattern matches `id`, `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, then `\K` omits the matched text and only 1+ chars other than `,` land in the match value.

Or, a capturing approach with `stringr::str_match` is also valid here:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_match(xx, "\\bid\\s*=\\s*([^,]+)")[,2]
[1] "wool"
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of regex here, you could `parse()` the string and grab the `id` argument by name.

```
as.character(parse(text = xx)[[1]]$id)
# [1] "wool"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also an elegant solution!